# curve fitting zipf distribution matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, zipf

I tried to fit the following plot(red dot) with the Zipf distribution PDF in Python, **F~x^(-a)**.  I simply chose `a=0.56` and plotted `y = x^(-0.56)`, and I got the curve shown below.

The curve is obviously wrong.  I don't know how to do the curve fitting.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Not sure what you are exactly looking for, but if you want to fit a model (function) to data, use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import zetac


def f(x, a):
    return (x**-a)/zetac(a)


result = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=[0.56])
p = result[0]

print p
```

If you don't trust the normalization, add a second parameter `b` and fit that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need an intercept in your loglog plot, right now it is 0.

That frequency *follows* the inverse rank implies that there is a ratio K between the frequency and the inverse rank, so you need to fit:

**F~x^(-a) => F = k/(x^a)**