# How to add a zipf curve to a bar plot of word frequency?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, zipf

```
plt.figure()
plt.bar([key for val,key in lst], [val for val,key in lst])
plt.xlabel("Terms")
plt.ylabel("Counts")
plt.show()
```

I have a list of tuples `(count, term)` that has been sorted in descending order of `count` (i.e the number of times a term appears in this document), and I plot the data as above. Now suppose I want to show that the distribution of terms violate the Zipf's Law in computational linguistics, can I add a Zipf's curve (f = c / rank) to this plot without altering the x-axis? How?

Comment: @JohanC This just changes the x-axis of my plot to numerical, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, a categorical x-axis is numbered `0,1,2,...`. To plot a curve at the same positions, use `range(len(lst))` for the x-values. As Zipf's Law calculates its values starting from 1, the corresponding y-values can be calculated as `zipf.pmf(p, alpha)` where p goes `1,2,3,...` and alpha is the zipf parameter. To align with the unnormalized bar plot, these values need to be multiplied by the total. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12038169/12046409) can be used to find the most fitting alpha.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import zipf

lst = [(60462, 'Italy'), (46755, 'Spain'), (10423, 'Greece'), (10197, 'Portugal'), (8737, 'Serbia'), (4105, 'Croatia'),
       (3281, 'Bosnia and\nHerzegovina'), (2878, 'Albania'), (2083, 'North\nMacedonia'), (2079, 'Slovenia'),
       (628, 'Montenegro'), (442, 'Malta'), (77, 'Andorra'), (34, 'San Marino'), (34, 'Gibraltar'), (1, 'Holy See')]

plt.bar([key for val, key in lst], [val for val, key in lst], color='limegreen')
alpha = 1.37065874
total = sum([p for p, c in lst])
plt.plot(range(len(lst)), [zipf.pmf(p, alpha) * total for p in range(1, len(lst) + 1)], color='crimson', lw=3)
plt.ylabel("Population")
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]